# Why can I no longer fetch a Github repo via `svn:external`?

Tags: github, svn, openssl

I used to be able to fetch projects from Github using SVN externals:

```
svn:externals > https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/tree/develop twitter-api-php
```

Github had [previously announced support for SVN,](https://blog.github.com/2011-10-20-improved-subversion-client-support/) and [this blog posts details the use of Github projects via SVN externals.](https://konstantin.blog/2012/github-projects-as-subversion-externals/)

This worked just fine previously, but I've noticed recently (the past couple of weeks?) that I can no longer fetch any project from Github: I get a `Unable to connect to a repository at URL ***` error. Other externals seem to be working as normal. I can't find any documentation that suggests they've dropped or changed this feature. Does anyone know why this is no longer working, or if they've dropped support?

**UPDATE:**
Running

```
svn ls https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/branches/develop
```

returns the following error:

```
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/branches/develop': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://github.com)
```

I'm guessing that's where my problem lies: my openssl version is `LibreSSl 2.27`, but I can't establish which version of TLS it uses, and in any instance I'm struggling to update `openssl`.

Answer (score 1):

The `svn:externals` property is evaluated by your local SVN-Client, not by Github. Therefore as long as Github support the SVN-bridge, `svn:externals` will work.

**But** your URL seems to be wrong:

```
> svn ls https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/tree/develop
svn: warning: W160013: URL 'https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/tree/develop' non-existent in revision 137
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
```

This URL seems to work:

```
> svn ls https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/branches/develop
.gitignore
.travis.yml
LICENSE.md
README.md
TwitterAPIExchange.php
composer.json
index.php
phpunit.xml
test/
```

Comment: When I run your example command it returns an SSL handshake error, which makes me think it's a problem with SSL in OSX rather than SVN directly. I'll do some more poking around...